# Rspec running generated tests based on hash content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Maybe i'm to blind to see right now, but i try to run a dynamic spec based on the contents of a hash. In this special case different versions of email-parts which should contain the same contents like scatched below:

```
context "testcontext" do
  before do
    #testsetup stuff
    @versions = {"Text-Version" => current_email.parts[0].body , "HTML-Version" => current_email.parts[1].body}
  end

  it "sets the correct subject" do
    current_email.subject.should =~ /subject_regex/
  end

  @versions.each do |key, body|

    it "test something in mail for #{key}" do
      body.should include("something i want to be there")
    end
  end
end
```

But @versions is nil then running the test.I expected it to be the value i have defined in the before block.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to "answer", but I think the before "setup" may only apply to the subsequent "describe" and "it" methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
before(:all) do
  #testsetup stuff
  @versions = {"Text-Version" => current_email.parts[0].body , "HTML-Version" =>     current_email.parts[1].body}
end
```

Comment: tried this but still get undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError), cause @version is nil

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
context "teh emailz" do
  @parts = [:text, :html]
  before do
    @versions = {:text => current_email.parts[0].body,
                :html => current_email.parts[1].body}
  end

  it "sets the correct subject" do
    current_email.subject.should =~ /subject_regex/
  end

  @parts.each do |name|
    it "test something the #{name} part of the body" do
      body = @versions[name]
      body.should include("something i want to be there")
    end
  end
end
```